# Sitecore personalisation - previous page

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

The website has these pages - Home, Product1, Product2 and the Home page has a banner.

When user's journey is - *Home > Product1 > Home*, the banner should show image1.

When user's journey is - *Home > Product2 > Home*, the banner should show image2.

When user visits - *Home > Product2 > Product1 > Home*, the banner should show image1.

..which means, I want to show the image based on the last visited page before *Home*.

In the rule set editor, I set the 3 rules:
1. where the specific page during the visit is "product1" , then the image will be image1.
2. where the specific page during the visit is "product2" , then the image will be image2.
3. Default - hide banner

This is not working as desired. If user visits product1 first, then its always image1 in the banner. I understand it's working according the rule, as rule 1 will always become true here.

But, how can I achieve what I need.

Comment: You can switch the order of rules #1 and #2, then image2 will have priority over image1. If that is not good enough for you—then yeah, you'll need to create a custom rule.

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to create a custom condition for that. There are [lots](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecore_what39s_new/posts/creating-custom-conditions-part-1) [of](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2013/09/10/custom-rules-and-conditions-for-sitecore-personalization/) [blogposts](http://:https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/device_detection/create_custom_rules_for_sitecore_device_detection) around how to do that part, so I won't focus on that.

Your condition could be something like `where previous page is specific page`

Then in your condition, you'll pass in an ID (where it says `specific page`). You can then do something like this in the condition:

```
var pagesVisited = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Interaction.GetPages().ToList();
return pagesVisited.Last().Item.Id == Guid.Parse(id); // id is the item you've selected in the Rule Editor
```

(Note that I haven't tested the code, but it should be similar to this. You might also want to run a bit of a performance test on it of course).

Comment: Is there a way, we can achieve this without any coding

Comment: No, I don't think you can, looking at the rules that are available in the system.